# Is there a way to migrate a neo4j database with its relationships included?

Tags: import, neo4j, migration, export

I was attempting to migrate the data of database in neo4j into a new database, set on a different machine.
In order to do so I ran the following command to create an export:

```
CALL apoc.export.cypher.query('MATCH (a:Object)-[r]-(b:Object) WHERE NOT a:Type1 AND NOT a:Type2 RETURN *', '/data/csv_destination/export.cypher',{format:'cypher-shell'});
```

After downloading the APOC library into the other database and placing the export file into the import folder, I tried to run this second command:

```
call apoc.cypher.runFile('export.cypher',{format:'cypher-shell'})
```

For some reason, it imports only the nodes, but not the relationships. I checked the export file and they are definitely specified. In case you wonder, the version of neo4j in the first database is 3.1.14, while on the second it is 4.2.0. Does anyone know how to solve this issue or provide any sort of help?

Comment: Probably best to use the database dump and load functionality

Answer (score 0):

As Tomaž says in the comments, your best bet here is to use the database dump utility. You can read more about making an [offline copy](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/offline-backup/), and [restoring one](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/restore-dump/).